# Connecting UCI engine with iOS?

Tags: engines, uci

So I'm not actually making a Chess app, but I am trying to hook up an engine that uses a protocol almost exactly the same as UCI. I can get it working quite easily on a macOS app. Now, the hard part is integrating an engine like Stockfish into an iOS app.

You can't use std input/output nor can you fork a process, so how should one manage the protocol for communicating moves to a UCI interface? I've managed to include the engine C++ library and can communicate via UCI commands in the debug console but I have no idea how to simulate std input into the engine from iOS. Should I look for hooks within the engine to call directly and simulate the game loop in Swift?

I apologize if this is the wrong community for this question, but UCI specific questions go over the head of most SO users so I thought I might try here. There are a plethora of iOS chess apps so I'm genuinely curious how people are integrating their engines into their apps.

Comment: FWIW, I did some digging around and found [this forum discussion](http://support.stockfishchess.org/discussions/problems/321-how-to-integrate-stockfish-in-ios-app) which includes [a link to the source for v2.2 of the iOS StockFish](http://support.stockfishchess.org/discussions/problems/321/r?go=aHR0cDovL2NsLmx5LzFPMHYzODBSM1AyYTJBMDQwNjBT) app. One can reverse engineer what they've done there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Inter-thread communication. Specific implementations could be:

- Internal UCI queues
- Find the UCI loop function then hook it up (e.g. UCI::loop in Stockfish).
- Redirect the standard input/output into pipes

Few points:

- It's not a good idea to do your works with Swift, because Swift has poor support for C++. I prefer Objective-C as it works with C++ at the source level.
- Redirecting is **recommended** if you're confident. All my iOS apps use that. You just need to send your UCI commands to a redirected pipe, while the engine receives them from the standard inputs (redirected). This is not a place for discussing unix programming, please ask Stackoverflow. It works.

Comment: do you use GCD to handle thread communication? What do you mean by UCI queues? is that like buffering commands? And lastly, how do you achieve that standard input/output via pipes? do you call some c function to do that?

Comment: I used std::thread for inter-thread. Queue for buffering UCI commands. Standard input/output redirection is possible with the pipe() command. @swigganicks

Comment: @SmallChess this post inspired me to make my own chess app integrating Stockfish. Thank you for all those advices, it helped me good. I would like to say though, I disagree with the "It's not a good idea to do your works with Swift". I started building an interface in C++ to talk with stockfish, and I refactored it later in Swift and I must say it works just fine (`dup` and `Pipe` act just the same if not better when it comes to handling stdout). The code is smaller and easier to understand for Swift only team members. once again thank you a lot for your post